# Promise always pending in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Why the following promise never resolves?

```
const x= new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(12),5000));
```

By writing, in the console,

```
const x= new Promise(resolve=>resolve(12))
```

am getting

```
`Promise {<fulfilled>: 12}`
```

By writing

```
const x= new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(12),5000))
```

am getting

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

Thought, that should change in fulfilled after 5 secs. But, it does not. Why?

Comment: Have you checked value of x after 5 seconds?

Comment: `Promise {<pending>}` is what the console returns when you create a new instance of a `Promise` that is yet to resolve. The console does not give you another message whenever the promise is in the fulfilled state. You'd have to check explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console is just showing you a snapshot of the *current state* of the Promise. It is not watching for changes to its state.

> Why the following promise never resolves?

You can clearly see this does resolve after 5 seconds:

```js
const x= new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(12),5000)) ;
x.then(result => console.log(result));
```